# Высота ячейки над клавиатурой

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Как узнать высоту ячейки над клавиатурой?
Это строка в которой отображаются исправления, предиктивный набор и т.д.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034997/quicktype-bar-on-the-keyboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, вам нужна полная высота клавиатуры. Ее можно получить, подписавшись на `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` уведомление:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
    CGFloat height = [note.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height;
    // меняем констрейнты с учетом высоты клавиатуры
}];
```

Высоту `accessoryView` можно вычислить отняв от полученного значения высоту стандартной клавиатуры (216 для портрета и 162 для ландшафта).

Comment: В том то и дело, что мне необходимо понять есть ли accessoryView, и если есть, то узнать его высоту, потому что на одном view используется обычная клавиатура и uipickerview, а они разной высоты. Когда переключаешься между разными TextField интерфейс прыгает на разницу высот клавиатур.

Comment: Тогда просто отнимите от полученной высоты высоту стандартной клавиатуры (добавил значения в ответ)

Comment: Спасибо. Сработало.